# How can I prove that there are infinitely many primes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, prime-factorization

Prove that there are infinitely many primes using the
following factorization for any $x$:
$x^4 + x^2 + 1 = (x^2 − x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)$.

a) Prove that for any even integer $x$, there does not exist a prime number $p$ such that $p \mid (x^2 − x + 1) $ and $p \mid (x^2 + x + 1).$

b) For $n\in \mathbb N$, define $a_n = 2^{2^n+1} + 2^{2^{n}}
+ 1$. Prove that $a_n$ has at least $n + 1$ distinct prime factors.

c) Use part (b) to prove that there are infinitely many primes

My Solution:

a) So my initial thought is to just prove this using "by way of contradiction". So that turns into the statement saying that there **does** exist some prime number such that it can divide either equations. We can also replace $x$ with $x = 2k $ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$ since $x$ is even. $p \mid ((2k)^2 - 2k +1) $ which is $p \mid (4k^2 -2k +1) $ **or** $p \mid (4k^2 + 2k + 1) $. Looking at this statements, I can tell that $p$ will be some odd prime number. So isn't 1 just that prime number $p$? So wouldn't the statement be false because the contradiction is true?

b) I solved this using induction.

c) Pretty straight forward after b) is solved.

Comment: Hint: If $p$ is a factor of both $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$, what other numbers is it also a factor of?

Comment: 1 is not a prime number, so no, p is not 1

Comment: @Michael It would also be a factor of $(x^2 +x +1)(x^2 -x +1)$

Comment: Hint: If $d$ divides $r$ and $s$, then it divides $r-s$.

Comment: Making any progress, Spencer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I believe I found a solution, thanks to all the help from the comments. I included it in an 'edit' within my post above, hopefully my solution makes sense.

Comment: Good. It's better if you post it as an answer. Then you can "accept" it, so the question doesn't keep recycling to the front page as "unanswered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to figure out a solution thanks to the comments, this is what I have. So proving by way of contradiction. $p \mid (x^2 -x +1)$ and $p \mid (x^2 +x+1)$ so $p \mid ((x^2 + x +1) - (x^2 -x +1))$ which means $ p \mid 2x $. 2 is THE lowest prime number since 1 isn't a prime number and since we're saying that $p$ is odd and some prime number, $p$ cannot divide $2$, so it must be able to divide $x$. We can use $p \mid (x^2 -x  +1)$ to state that $pk = x^2-x+1$ where $k \in $ Z. Rearrange that to form $\frac{x^2-x+1}{p} = k$ and simplify this to form $k = \frac{x^2}{p} - \frac{x}{p} + \frac{1}{p} $. We already know that $p \mid x$ so $p \mid x^2$ meaning that $\frac{x^2}{p} \in Z$  and $\frac{x}{p} \in Z$. So to satisfy our equation, we need $\frac{1}{p} \in Z$ but that can only occur when $p = 1$ but $p$ has to be a prime number and 1 is not a prime number, therefore we have a contradiction.

Comment: Incidentally, there's a much cleaner way of proving your final assertion: you've established that $p\mid x$ and $p\mid(x^2-x+1)$. Since $p\mid x$, $p\mid x\cdot(x-1)$; in other words, $p\mid(x^2-x)$. Now, since $p\mid (x^2-x)$ and $p\mid (x^2-x+1)$, then using the same trick as you used to find $p\mid x$, we get that $p\mid \left((x^2-x+1)-(x^2-x)\right)$; in other words, $p\mid 1$, which is obviously contradictory. (This is essentially the same argument as yours - just presented in a cleaner way.)